# MySQL giving back unique ID on duplicate, how?

Tags: php, mysql, unique, fetch

Ive got a unique key on a few fields in a table. With PHP I get a nice error like it should when I try to insert the same data. What Im trying to archieve is that MySQL gives me back the primary key of the field that generated the error.

So when I insert something duplicate, is there any way that MySQL can give back the 'origional' ID without selecting all the fields Ive been trying to insert?

Tnx in advance

Comment: What do you need? A way to identify table's unique keys?

Comment: Not without asking it directly, no.

Comment: When I try to insert X into table Y when X already exists, I need MySQL to give me back the primary key of X that exists , without having to do a seperate SELECT on X in Y

Comment: "nice error"? really? I have never seen a nice error, ever. All errors I have seen are annoying :)

Comment: @Pokepoke: there is no such feature in mysql

Comment: @Pavanred: they should be so ;-) Otherwise they never will be fixed ;-)

Comment: Tnx guys, hoped there was such a functionality.

Comment: If you explain what you want to do when you get the ID maybe you will get some good suggestions. Otherwise, can't see why would you need an ID of an existing record if you know you can get to it with another query (unless you are trying to save yourself from running another query, but again knowing only ID from the other record seems meaningless - as it is probably a meaningless autonumber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql can't do that.. maybe if you will make procedure or function for this it is posible but you shoud think are you realy need this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysql_error()` to get a message like `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'` which you can then parse to figure out what the duplicate key value is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AUTO_INCREMENT field (`id`, or something else) you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` to have the LAST_INSERT_ID value return the value of the `id` column when an insert "failed". It will however, not fail anymore, which is something to take into consideration.